# Why does my <button> not show up after function?

Tags: javascript

I want a "See your input" button appear only after fields are filled. But struggling to make the button appear. Please advise.

```js
function notify() {
  alert("Welcome to my form");
  var name = prompt("Enter your name");
  var city = prompt("Which city you are living in");
  var mobile = prompt("Enter your phone number");
}

function nextStep() {
  var a = document.getElementById("showUp");
  if (a.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Your name is " + name;
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "Your city is " + city;
    document.getElementById("mobile").innerHTML = "Your phone number is " + mobile;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>
<button onclick="notify()">Try it</button>
<div id="showUp" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="nextStep()">See your input</button>
</div>
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="city"></p>
<p id="mobile"></p>
```

Comment: Your `nextStep` call is inside hidden element, so it's never actually called. Maybe try calling it from `notify`?

Comment: Where are you getting  x.style.display = "none"; from?  also your nextStep function is hidden.

Comment: And your `var name` is only visible inside that function, not globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing executing the function `nextStep()`.

You need to call the function `nextStep()` after the prompts.

You have **bound** your function to the button on click. But because the user can't see the button it won't run.

A function is only executed by calling it after it's been defined.

```
function myFunc() {
// do thing
}

myFunc(); // This executes the function above.
```

```
function notify() {
  alert("Welcome to my form");
  var name = prompt("Enter your name");
  var city = prompt("Which city you are living in");
  var mobile = prompt("Enter your phone number");

  nextStep(); // Add
}
```

Or you could move the logic from your `showUp()` function that displays the button into the `notify()` function.

```
var name;
var city;
var mobile;

function notify() {
  alert("Welcome to my form");
  name = prompt("Enter your name");
  city = prompt("Which city you are living in");
  mobile = prompt("Enter your phone number");

  showButton();
}

function showButton() {
  var a = document.getElementById("showUp");
  if (a.style.display === "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function nextStep() {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Your name is " + name;
  document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "Your city is " + city;
  document.getElementById("mobile").innerHTML = "Your phone number is " + mobile;
}
```

Comment: If he *only* wants fo display the button, then he can just put `document.getElementById("showUp").style.display = "block";` instead of `nextStep();` here.

Comment: @mr.mams I'm aware. I believe the confusion is in the fundamentals. Not the specifics.

Comment: you are completely right. But my point was more about getting closer to the "requirements" : when learning fundamentals, it is also important to stick to the requirements as much as possible (or to elicit them properly, depending on where the OP got that requirement from).

Comment: The input will show up without user clicking the button though. I'm not sure what the problem is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here;

1. after submitting all desired values show button inside `notify()`, prompts and alerts stop execution of the rest of the script until they are done, so button will show after everything is filled.
2. in order to use those values in both functions  you need to declare variables  outside of both functions and fill them in inside `notify()`
3. Call `nextStep()` on button click and use tho0se varibales.

```js
var name="";
var city ="";
var mobile ="";
// 1. first declare varibales outside of functions


function notify() {
  alert("Welcome to my form");
  
  name = prompt("Enter your name");
  city = prompt("Which city you are living in");
  mobile = prompt("Enter your phone number");
// 2. fill variables with data  
  
  var a = document.getElementById("showUp");
  a.style.display = "block";
// 3. show button after   prompt's are done
}

function nextStep() {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Your name is " + name;
    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "Your city is " + city;
    document.getElementById("mobile").innerHTML = "Your phone number is " + mobile;
// 4. now you can use those varaibles with data to show to user    
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display an alert box.</p>
<button onclick="notify()">Try it</button>
<div id="showUp" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="nextStep()">See your input</button>
</div>
<p id="name"></p>
<p id="city"></p>
<p id="mobile"></p>
```

Comment: The data collected for name, city and mobile won't show up in this case. It's [object HTMLParagraphElement] instead.

Comment: @p_w_hh [Look into JavaScript scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: @p_w_hh You have working example in front of you. Take a good look at my comment and changes that I made. It is working the way I made it in snippet, press run code snippet. If it didn't show values it means you haven't declare variables first outside of functions like I did, then fill them with data inside. Also order of things is very important.

Comment: Brilliant! I got it, probably biggest mistake was that I got confused between global and local variable, I feel so bad. Thank you so much for clearing this out

Comment: @p_w_hh No problem, its all learning process. JS scope can be tricky at start and even later for more complex builds. May I ask why did you  accepted least voted answer that does not really solve all problems you where facing, and it is not best solution to your problem overall? It will be confusing to anyone reading this topic...

Answer (score -1):

make a div

```
<div id="seeYourInputButton"></div>
```

after taking prompt write this

```
document.getElementById("seeYourInputButton").innerHTML = "<button onClick="nextStep()" >See your Input</button>
```